# cross page posting

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, c#-4.0

i am just trying the example of cross page posting.
i have added 1 textbox & 1 button to default.aspx page

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
 <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button"  PostBackUrl="~/About.aspx"/>
```

i have added following code to code-behind file of about.aspx page

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.PreviousPage != null)
        {
            TextBox SourceTextBox =
                (TextBox)Page.PreviousPage.FindControl("TextBox1");
            if (SourceTextBox != null)
            {
                Label1.Text = SourceTextBox.Text;
            }
            else
                Label1.Text = "no value";
        }
        else
            Label1.Text = "no value from previous page";
    }
```

when i enters some text in textbox1 & clicks button, it goes to about.aspx but label shows value "no value", its not showing textbox1's text value, why this is not working properly?

Comment: I just made exactly this example and its works ! So maybe you use and a master page ! ?

Comment: @Aristos: yeah i have added master page Site.master

Comment: Thats why, the PreviousPage is the master page, there you must locate the content, then the control.

Comment: @Aristos: no nothing, it just happen accidently, your answer is correct & well one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have master page then the code `Page.PreviousPage.FindControl("TextBox1");` not work because the `TextBox1` is under the `ContentPlaceHolder.` and must first locate the `ContentPlaceHolder.` and then find the `TextBox1`

But there is an easiest way to get the value as:

Place this on the previous page:

```
public string TextFromBox1
{
    get
    {
        return TextBox1.Text;
    }
}
```

and on the redirect page declare what is the previous page on aspx as:

```
<%@ Reference Page ="~/PreviousPageName.aspx" %>
```

and on code behind get the value as:

```
if (Page.PreviousPage != null)
{
    if (Page.PreviousPage is PreviousPageClassName)
    {
        Label1.Text = ((PreviousPageClassName)Page.PreviousPage).TextFromBox1;
    }
    else
    {
        Label1.Text = "no value";
    }
}
else
    Label1.Text = "no value from previous page";
```

Comment: I tested and working. With out master page your code is working, but with master page this is the way.