# How To Pass Dynamically created value into another page..?

Tags: html, asp.net, c#-4.0

i am dynamically create contents and buttons into my code behind "**tree.aspx.cs**" page

```
sbmainTbl.AppendFormat("<tr><td><div class=\"a\">{0}<div class=\"details\"<p id=\"p\">{1}</p><ul><li>Parent-UnitId:{2}</li><li>Address :{3}</li><li>City: {4}</li><li>EmailId: {5}</li><li>PhoneNo: {6}</li><li>FaxNo: {7}</li><li><input type=\"button\" value=\"ADD\"  onclick=\"f2();\" /></li></ul></div></div></div></td></tr>",
            CellText(dtparent.Rows[0]["UnitName"].ToString()),
            CellText(dtparent.Rows[0]["UnitName"].ToString()),
            CellText(dtparent.Rows[0]["ParentUnitId"].ToString()),
            CellText(dtparent.Rows[0]["Address"].ToString()),
            CellText(dtparent.Rows[0]["City"].ToString()),
            CellText(dtparent.Rows[0]["EmailId"].ToString()),
            CellText(dtparent.Rows[0]["PhoneNo"].ToString()),
        CellText(dtparent.Rows[0]["FaxNo"].ToString()));
```

Now i have another page called "**Add.aspx Page**"
in that page i have textbox

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtunitname" runat="server" CssClass="textbox"></asp:TextBox>
```

now i just want on click on dynamically create button on "**tree.aspx**" page the "unitname(dynamically create value)" will pass "**Add.aspx**" page and textbox should fill with unitname.

kindly help me,
Thanks.

Comment: Are we talking about two pages in two browser tabs/windows? Or do you call tree.aspx, press a button and navigate to add.aspx?

Comment: you can store the value in [sessions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx) and get the session value in another page.

Comment: i call tree.aspx page and on press dynamic create button i will navigate to add.aspx page.

Comment: Well then, either write the values into the Session, as @Ravimallya suggests, or hand the values over in the Query Parameter.

Comment: well the problem is that the contents i have created dynamically are in a <div> and the <div> appeared lot of times in page and every time it's have different values thats why i create a dynamic button along this and on clicking that button the values in that specific <div> navigate to Add.aspx page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass pass values using asp.net you need to follow the asp.net way.

First on the first page you place that value on a page control, I prefer on your case a hidden  field, that is also post back to any page.

Then you add your value to that field

```
ValueHiddenField.value = CellText(dtparent.Rows[0]["UnitName"].ToString())
```

and you make also a public field so the second page can read it

```
public string ValueHiddenField
{
    get
    {
        return ValueHiddenField.value;
    }
}
```

And you say to the button to post back to the second page using the `PostBackUrl` field of the button.

Now this is the way you get your data from second page:
On the redirect page declare what is the previous page on aspx as:

```
<%@ Reference Page ="~/PreviousPageName.aspx" %>
```

and on code behind on second page you get the value as:

```
if (Page.PreviousPage != null)
{
    if (Page.PreviousPage is PreviousPageClassName)
    {
        Label1.Text = ((PreviousPageClassName)Page.PreviousPage).ValueHiddenField;
    }
    else
    {
        Label1.Text = "no value";
    }
}
else
    Label1.Text = "no value from previous page";
```

Similar answers:
[cross page posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13208939/cross-page-posting/13209095#13209095)
[Cross-page posting. Is it a good pratice to use PreviousPage in Asp.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10124030/cross-page-posting-is-it-a-good-pratice-to-use-previouspage-in-asp-net/10124789#10124789)

Comment: hi @Aristos i am doing the same but the problem is i am getting Page.PreviousPage = null so can't go in the first loop. help me to fix it

Comment: @akvickyit7 You can also use the `Form[]` to direct read all posted values.